# change color of child element onclick parent element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the given snippet, I have given the code and I expect the result that on the parent div when I click again the default color should apply on the child element. but the condition is the code should be as minimal as possible.

need a solution(if possible) without .toggleclass, .toggle, .addclass, .removeclass.

thank you.

***EDITED** Thank you so much all of you for your valuable answers. I appreciate that. motto=> improve your knowledge bank.

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).children().css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
})
```

```css
.ancestors * {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
    <ul>ul (grandparent)
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using jQuery you can use `.toggleClass` to switch between two CSS classes, one with the new color and one with the default color.
Here is the reference for `toggleClass`, you can see first demo example is doing what I understand that you want: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: need a solution(if possible) without .toggleclass, .toggle, .addclass, .removeclass.

Comment: Why do you want to apply inline style directly instead of using a class (with .addClass or .removeClass or likewise)?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code will help you without adding or removing any class or toggle.  check this ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T0yVIuzEuXMDOzjvvyCuwSblEHNLRt-P/view )

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <style>
    .ancestors * { 
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid lightgrey;
      color: lightgrey;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 15px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
      <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
        <ul>ul (grandparent)  
          <li>li (direct parent)
            <span>span</span>
          </li>
          <li>li (direct parent)
            <span>span</span>
          </li>
          <li>li (direct parent)
            <span>span</span>
          </li>
        </ul>   
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li').click(function(){
          if ($(this).children().attr("style") != "") {
            $(this).children().attr("style","");
          }else{
            $(this).children().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
          }
        })
      })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.addClass` function

```
$('.parentClass').addClass("new-class-for-parent");
```

**Edited:**
With "need a solution(if possible) without .toggleclass, .toggle, .addclass, .removeclass.", you can also use `.prop` function like so:

```
$('.parentClass').prop("style","color:#f0f0f0;width:100px;");
//or
$('#parentClass').prop("class","class-for-this");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element attribute "style" to identify color applied or not, check below code -

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var is_color = $(this).children().attr('style');

    if (typeof is_color !== typeof undefined && is_color !== false) {
        $(this).children().removeAttr("style");
    }
    else {
        $(this).children().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass()` for toggle multiple classes. You can use the below code it is working properly according to your needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $("span").toggleClass("child");
    });
});
```

```css
.ancestors * {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}

.child {
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body class="ancestors">
    <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
        <ul>ul (grandparent)
            <li>li (direct parent)
                <span>span</span>
            </li>
            <li>li (direct parent)
                <span>span</span>
            </li>
            <li>li (direct parent)
                <span>span</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without class like this if you want

```js
$('li').click(function(){
 $(this).children().attr('data-red', "true");
})
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
[data-red="true"]{
  color:red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</head>

<body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
    <ul>ul (grandparent)  
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```